# The difference between の中で vs の中から

Tags: verbs, particle-で, particle-から

This comes from a previous [previous question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2503/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%AD-%E3%81%AB-%E3%81%A7-%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89-what-is-the-correct-choice-of-particles/2520#2520) with what I find to be a confusing explanation.

Generally, の中で is presented in all of the English language resources I could find to be an atomic thing that lets one express the idea "from within these. "

For example (pulled from Bunpro):

> この中で一つを選んでください。

> グループの中で色々な意見がありました。

When not presented after a demonstritive pronoun で can suffice.

> グループで色々な意見がありました。

の中で can also just mean "within" like で on its own:

> 公園の中で子供達が遊んでいた。

From the link to the previous Stack Exchange question, it seems that the first usage of の中で can be replaced by の中から:

> この中から一つを選んでください。

> グループの中から色々な意見がありました。

However, the answers seemed to both indicate that this is ungrammatical:

> 私はその中で好きな家を借りました

Since で should be から because the verb is 借る. Why is this? What makes 借る different here?

Comment: Is 一ひ supposed to be 一つ?

Comment: Yes sorry thay was a typo on my part. I had copy and pasted from Bunpro and that carried over furigana, and for some reason I had deleted the つ and a ひ got in there somehow.

Comment: で and の中で are not wholly interchangeable.  In your example, 「公園（の中）で子供達が遊んでいた」, the meaning shifts if we remove the の中.  It's basically the difference in English between "at the park" and "in the park".  Note too the difference between で ("at", in many of your examples) and から ("from").  If the action of the verb or statement involves an outward or exclusionary action, から is more appropriate.  For instance, 選ぶ means you're **choosing from** a selection, and **excluding** the others.  Similar for your last sentence with 借りる.

Comment: But, for clarification, の中で should be interchangeable with の中から though, right? That is the main thrust of the question, since the linked to solution seems to claim that they aren't.